# Allow only one custom user-agent to execute PHP code

Tags: php, user-agent

I have searched for days for simple solution and turned up nothing. See tons of information on using .htaccess, but nothing for simple PHP solution.

Using the mongoose server in project for desktop app and does not support .htaccess like most others, so need a solution for PHP (and/or even javascript).

I can set a custom user-agent and I need to only allow it to execute the PHP scripts/pages.

Mongoose does not use standard htaccess file like most portable servers used in Windows/MAC environment. Can only use limited entries hence I need a PHP solution. I simply need working solution for "HTTP_USER_AGENT" to place in PHP file which prevents people from accessing without my custom user-agent.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Since the app is being used in closed environment and does not have access to internet, not so much worried about security. Basically it is an app used in classroom (school) and students answer yes/no questions after watching a video. Easy way to see if they are grasping info before testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-Agent is not a good parameter to use to restrict usage to a PHP script. At the very least, you would want to use some sort of public API key with a private key that calculates an HMAC SHA256 hash on content.

In PHP, you could try to restrict users by IP address. Again, this is not good practice - so be careful. Also make sure to check for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, especially if you're behind a firewall.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Since the app is being used in closed environment and does not have access to internet, not so much worried about security. Basically it is an app used in classroom (school) and students answer yes/no questions after watching a video. Easy way to see if they are grasping info before testing. All I need is to protect some PHP files in case they use browser and not software app.